# CALayer OpenGL(-ES) texture memory usage

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, calayer, textures, video-memory

I have an iPhone app that uses too much texture memory. I am trying to figure out which of the app's CALayers uses too much texture memory.

Unfortunately, I cannot figure out how much texture memory a specific CALayer is using.

Are there any good tricks I can use ?

Comment: Do you mean that if the contents property is not nil it uses texture memory ? I am really in a struggle finding any definite documentation on this.

Comment: It caches contents to card... I am not sure about "texture memory", and how you came to that. (Were you profiling with instruments?...)

Comment: Yep instruments shows lots of opengl texture memory being allocated. The app is only using calayer based apis. It doesnt use opengl directly.

Comment: Do you need to go that far? You said that using Core Animation API only? (Just curious.)

Comment: Yes - the texture memory goes that high that the app is getting killed by iOS. However, the project is that big, that is it not clear which CALayer uses how much texture memory.